# PHP implode not working

Tags: php, implode

I'm trying to take a table that has rows of sessions and page urls and put them in a table with each row containing the session and all the pages visited separated by a '|'.

The code below is only returning sessions with no URL's next to it. Any ideas on what I did wrong here?

```
<?php
$html = "<table>\n";
$html .= "<tr>\n<th>SESSION</th>\n<th>PATH</th>\n</tr>\n";
$paths = array();
$sql = "SELECT session_id, page_url FROM pageviews";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$got_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($got_rows) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        array_push($paths[$row['session_id']], $row['page_url']);
    }

    foreach ($paths as $session => $page) {
        $html .= "<tr>\n";
        $html .= '<td>' . $session . "</td>\n";
        $html .= '<td>' . implode('| ', $page) . "</td>\n";
        $html .= "</tr>\n";
    }

} else {
    $html .= '<td colspan="2">No results</td>' . "\n";
}

$html .= "</table>\n";
echo $html;

if (!mysqli_query($conn,$sql))  {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Gives me NULL but the table is full of entries

Comment: The code change seems to be loading a blank screen now.  There is a call to include init earlier on, that works fine.

Comment: Fixed the error, was mussing a [ in yours.  So I get this:

Array
(
    [f637f5a85f8c911f596e2cfe775a1f16] => leadfactory.ca/analytics/testpage2.php
    [74e1ad9b538632afce44fd732f318a79] => leadfactory.ca/analytics/testpage2.php
)

What I now realize this is doing is returning only unique sessions and not listing a single session more than once with all the pages.

Comment: seems like the initial sql query is part of the issue.  It's deduping on session_ids for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you turn on error reporting, you should receive error messages for the `array_push()`:

> Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

See: [3v4l.org example of error](https://3v4l.org/aCsWi)

In your example, you've defined the array as:

```
$paths = array();
```

However, in your `while()` you attempt to add new items to a non-existent array:

```
array_push($paths[$row['session_id']], $row['page_url']);
// $paths[$row['session_id']] hasn't been defined as an array, which array_push() expects
```

Something like this should solve your issue:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    // Create an array for the session_id if it doesn't exist yet
    if ( ! array_key_exists($row['session_id'], $paths) || ! is_array($paths[$row['session_id']])) {
        $paths[$row['session_id']] = [];
    }

    // Add to the array now that we know it exists
    array_push($paths[$row['session_id']], $row['page_url']);
}
```

See: [3v4l.org working example](https://3v4l.org/OibBS)

As a sidenote, you can remove the `array_push($arr, $var)` and simply use `$arr[] = $var` which is faster. From the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php):

> Note: If you use `array_push()` to add one element to the array it's better to use `$array[] =` because in that way there is no overhead of calling a function.